# How to theme a custom block

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I've created a block using `hook_block_info` and `hook_block_theme` and the like. But how can I theme it?

I have it working to return an array with the keys `'subject'` and `'content'`. But I created the markup directly in the `hook_block_view()` hook and that's not what I want.

In the docs it's said that content should preferably returned as *renderable array* and not as markup. But what is this *renderable array*? They say it should be data instead of markup, but all I see in the examples is that it's just used as a wrapper for markup, so nothing gained there.

I want to be able to have a `block--MYMODULE--DELTA.tpl.php` in my theme but how do I call it and how can I pass the data to the block?

Comment: detail blog: http://goo.gl/kD3TZu

Comment: @SureshKamrushi – OP asks for theming a block. The linked article is about adding a new region to a theme. Which is not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The way I do this is as follows...

```
function MYMODULE_block_info() {

  $blocks = [];

  $blocks['my_block_machine_name'] = [
    'info'  => t('My Block Title'),
    // @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/group/block_caching/7.x
    // You can use different caching options.
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  ];

  return $blocks;
}

function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {

  $block = [];

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_block_machine_name':
      // Good idea to check user permissions here.
      if (user_access('access content')) {
        $block['subject'] = t('My Block Title');
        $block['content'] = MY_BLOCK_CONTENT_CALLBACK();
      }
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}

function MY_BLOCK_CONTENT_CALLBACK()() {

  $items = [];

  // This is the simplest kind of renderable array.
  $items['VAR_ONE'] = ['#markup' => 'VAR_ONE_OUTPUT'];

  // Here I added a prefix and a suffix.
  $items['VAR_TWO'] = [
    '#prefix' => '<div class="foo-bar">',
    '#markup' => 'VAR_TWO_OUTPUT',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];

  // This is where the $items get sent to your my-template.tpl.php template
  // that got registered below.
  return theme('my_cool_block', ['items' => $items]);
}

function MYMODULE_theme() {

  // Here you are registering your template for the block output above.
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');

  // Drupal will now look up your modules /theme folder first to grab the
  // template.
  $base = [
    'path' => "$module_path/theme",
  ];

  return [
    'my_cool_block' => $base + [
        // Leave off .tpl.php.
        'template'  => 'my-template',
        // Define variables you want to pass to the template.
        // Here I just pass items, but you can pass any other data as well.
        'variables' => [
          'items' => NULL,
        ],
      ],
  ];
}
```

And then in a subfolder in your module called `theme` there should be a file called `my-template.tpl.php` which could have this in it:

```
<?php 

$items = $variables['items'];

print render($items['VAR_ONE']); 
print render($items['VAR_TWO']);
```

And if you wanted to, you could actually overwrite the "default" module implementation you just made for `my-module.tpl.php` in your theme as you wish in `block--MYMODULE--DELTA.tpl.php`.

Comment: But if I overule the theme with a tpl.php file in my theme, the hook_block_view won't execute and my variables are not given to the temmplate file.

Comment: @yunzen - You might need to empty you cache, try going to `admin/config/development/performance` and click the `clear cache` button. You can also clear the cache using drush i.e `drush cc all`

Answer (score 6):

Try [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module. When you have enabled it you can check a checkbox in bottom left corner of you Drupal page. After that you can click on your block and get useful information considering theming. You can see the possible .tpl.php file namings for your block for example.

Pick one of those names. The first is the most specific one. It will only theme one block. Create a file with that name in your theme folder if it's not already there. You can put it in subfolder if you want to get organized.

Copy the content of [block.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/11813) in your file and start changing things to the way you want them to be.

Save your file, clear caches and reload the page.

Answer (score 5):

There's already a number of answers for this question but I have tried to provide a very simplistic approach. Hopefully identifying to devs the array structure expected by Drupal when returning your block content.

To do this I have broken the question down into separate code examples as such,

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function examplemodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'examplemodule_output' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'title' => NULL,
        'content' => NULL,
        'popular_content' => NULL,
       ),
      'template' => 'templates/examplemodule-sweet--block',
    ),
  );
}
```

Please see a full explanation here [drupal 7 creating theming custom blocks](http://legomenon.io/article/drupal-7-creating-theming-custom-block-content)

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post, but I have found a better solution for overriding block templates from a custom module for Drupal 7.

Add this to your custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  // Custom template for that overrides the default block.tpl.php.
  $themes['block__my_custom_module'] = [
    'template'      => 'block--my_custom_module',
    'original hook' => 'block',
    'path'          => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_custom_module') . '/templates',
  ];

  return $themes;
}
```

Then you need the follow code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_info() {

  $blocks = [];

  $blocks['my_custom_module'] = [
    'info'  => t('My Custom Module Block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  ];

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {

  $block = [];

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_custom_module':
      $block['content'] = _my_custom_module_helper_function();
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}

/**
 * Helper function to generate HTML.
 *
 * @return string
 *   generated HTML
 */
function _my_custom_module_helper_function() {

  $output = '';

  // ...

  return $output;
}
```

All you have to do is create `templates/block--my-custom-module.tpl.php` inside your module's folder.

I have written a tutorial about this [Drupal Tutorial - How to Override a Block Templates from a Custom Module](http://www.strykerenterprise.com/blog/drupal-tutorial-how-override-block-templates-custom-module)