# How do I get block content to show?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I have a custom module that I created. In it, I've implemented the `hook_block_view`:

```
function event_details_block_view($delta = '') {
$block = array();

switch($delta) {
    case 'event_details':
    $block['content'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'event_block_details',
    );
    break;
}

return $block;
}
```

I then have a file named `event-block-details.tpl.php` in my module folder. Right now, this is just some basic HTML to test whether or not the block is accepting the theme. When I go to my site however, I am able to see the block in the blocks tab and I can add it to a page, but none of the content displays.

Are there any suggestions as to what could be wrong? This is the first module I've written so I'm unsure where the errors can lie. I use Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check this link for solving your problem : [how-to-theme-a-custom-block-in-drupal-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39023/how-to-theme-a-custom-block-in-drupal-7). Actually you can search for that type of question around here.